Replacement for Toast.setView() from a foreground Activity
Toast.setView(view) was deprecated in Android API 30. The recommended replacement is Snackbar from the Material library.
With Toast.setView() we are able to set a custom View including images to provide a really nice short message experience for the user. I use this to good effect in my games. Toast also allows you to set the gravity for the Toast to put it into a spot on the screen that is relevant for your app.
While (as of Android API 34) we can still use Toast.setView() the fact that it is deprecated means that it will be removed at some point in the future.
So I want to know what is a viable like for like replacement?
Toast allows:

Custom View
Positioning on the screen
No user interaction
Automatically disappears

Snackbar (recommended replacement) provides:

No custom View
No screen positioning
No user interaction
Automatically disappears

Dialog (possible replacement)

Custom View
Screen positioning
Captures user input, occluding the Activity below it
Requires code to auto dismiss

Neither of the 2 options above works well. Snackbar not at all, and dialog's grabbing of user input will provide a really poor user experience.
There is discussion here Method Toast.setView is deprecated but no solution.

No-one?? Really?

The "no user interaction" requirement is a problem. For example, a snackbar supports user interaction: swipes, actions, etc. One of the reasons Google is minimizing the flexibility of Toast is because of its use by malware specifically because it is invisible to user input.

@CommonsWare I understand that security requirement when a Toast is displayed from a backgrounded app, but not when your app is in the foreground.  This change has really annoyed my users.

Note that Snackbars, as a pattern, do allow custom views - that's exactly why Snackbar extends BaseTransientBottomBar.

@ianhanniballake there is no no indicator that that is possible in the Snackbar API, nor could I find any documentation to suggest otherwise.
